# Why does the admob count impressions on the wrong account?

Tags: android, admob, godot

I put the game in the play market, the ads were displayed correctly. Later I was banned and the ads stopped showing. I created a new account, changed all the keys for the new account, posted the update to the play market. But impressions appear in the old account, not in the new one. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the case that your users are on an older version of your application that has the old AdMob keys.

You might need to reach out to your audience to update to the latest version which has the latest keys.

Comment: No, I update my app on my phone and show my ads. But showings doesn't appear on new admob account. I think this problem because admob banned application with my pachage name.